# how to set value of hidden or text field when user clicks save in prestashop1.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to change the value of a field in   $this->fields_form  when  submit is clicked ie before the value enters into the table i want to change the forms value in which i am going to insert

```
 // This  form is populated  when  add or edit is clicked
   public function renderForm()
  {
    $years        = Tools::dateYears();
    $months       = Tools::dateMonths();
    $days         = Tools::dateDays();
    $ticketSeries = Winners::getTicketSeries();
    $prdtCategory = Winners::getProductCategory();
    $nationality  = Winners::getNationality();
    $firstArray = 
             array(array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Name'),
                'name' => 'name',
                'required' => true,
                'col' => '4',
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
            ),
               array(
                'type'     => 'file',
                'label'    => $this->l('Winner Image'),
                'name'     => 'winner_image',
                'display_image' => true,
                'required' => false
            ),
             array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Ticket No'),
                'name' => 'ticket_no',
                'required' => true,
                'col' => '4',
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Ticket Series'),
                'name' => 'series',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => $ticketSeries,
                    'id' => 'ticket_series_name',
                    'name' => 'ticket_series_name'
                ),
                'col' => '4',
                'hint' => array(
                    $this->l('The ticket series of each draw !!.')
                )
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Category'),
                'name' => 'category',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => $prdtCategory,
                    'id' => 'name',
                    'name' => 'name'
                ),
                'col' => '4',
                'hint' => array(
                    $this->l('Product Category.')
                )
            ),

            array(
                'type' => 'date',
                'label' => $this->l('Draw Date:'),
                'name' => 'draw_date',
                'size' => 10,
                'required' => true,
                'desc' => $this->l('The draw date of this series'),
            ),
                array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label' => $this->l('Nationality'),
                'name' => 'nationality',
                'required' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'query' => $nationality,
                    'id' => 'name',
                    'name' => 'name'
                ),
                'col' => '4',
                'hint' => array(
                    $this->l('Nationality the winner Belongs .')
                )
            ),

            array(
                'type' => 'textarea',
                'label' => $this->l('Testimonial'),
                'name' => 'testimonial',
                'required' => true,
                'autoload_rte' => true,
                'rows' => 7,
                'cols' => 40,
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' <>;=#{}'
            ), //  add  tag  'autoload_rte' => true, 'lang' => true, --> lang i removed 
               // since the editor value did not submit  editor                  
        );

    if (Tools::getIsset('addkits_winners') ){
            $secondArray = array(
             array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'label' => $this->l('Add Date'),
                'name' => 'date_add',                   
                'col' => '4',                   
                'values'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
            ),
            array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'label' => $this->l('Winner Image Name'),
                'name' => 'winner_image_name',                   
                'col' => '4',                   
                'values'=>"defalt_value"
            )
            );
            $mainArray = array_merge($firstArray,$secondArray); 
         }  

         if (Tools::getIsset('updatekits_winners') ){
            $thirdArray = array(
             array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'label' => $this->l('Update Date'),
                'name' => 'date_upd',                   
                'col' => '4',                   
                'values'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'hint' => $this->l('Invalid characters:').' 0-9!&lt;&gt;,;?=+()@#"°{}_$%:'
            ),
                array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => $this->l('Winner Image Name'),
                'name' => 'winner_image_name',                   
                'col' => '4',                   
                'values'=>"defalt_value"
            ));
            $mainArray = array_merge($firstArray,$thirdArray); 
         }  


    $this->fields_form = array(
        'tinymce' => true,
        'legend' => array(
            'title' => $this->l('Configure your Winner'),
            'icon' => 'icon-user'
        ),          
        'input' => $mainArray
    );
    //Assign value to hidden 
    $this->fields_value['date_add'] = $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $this->fields_value['winner_image_name'] ="default_image.jpg";
    $this->fields_form['submit'] = array(
        'title' => $this->l('Save'),
    );
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $this->addJqueryUI('ui.datepicker');

   return parent::renderForm();
}











 public function postProcess()
 {
   $this->getContent();
    $winner_image_name         = (string) Tools::getValue('winner_image_name');
    // d($winner_image_name);
    parent::postProcess();

}
```

Here  i want  to change the value of  winner_image_name (field) ie when  the image is uploaed  i want to change the field name and  if the image is not uploaded i want to keep the default value

```
public function getContent()
  { 
    $output = null;     

    if( Tools::isSubmit('submitAddkits_winners') )
    {           
         // d("rechaed  here");      
        $winner_image      = $_FILES['winner_image'];
        $ticket_no         = (string) Tools::getValue('ticket_no');
        //d($ticket_no);

        if( $winner_image['name'] != "" )
        {
            //Format allowed i
            $allowed = array('image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png');

            //check allowed formats
            if( in_array($winner_image['type'], $allowed) )
            {
                $path = '../modules/addwinners/';
                $ext = pathinfo($winner_image['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

               $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '_'.$ticket_no;
               $this->fields_value['winner_image_name']=$newfilename.".".$ext;
               $helper->fields_value['winner_image_name'] = "";

                if( ! move_uploaded_file($winner_image['tmp_name'], $path.$newfilename.".".$ext) )
                {
                    $output .= $this->displayError( $path.$stilogo_image['name'] );
                    return $output.$this->displayForm();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $output .= $this->displayError( $this->l('Image formated Not Supported.') );
                return $output.$this->displayForm();
            }
        }   



        //Se arrivo qui è perchè tutti i campi obbligatori sono stati riempiti quindi aggiorno i valori

        //Configuration::updateValue('STILOGOPOPUP_IMAGE', $winner_image['name']);

      //  $output .= $this->displayConfirmation( $this->l('Impostazioni salvate') );                      
    }   

    return $output.$this->html;;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use postProcess instead OR another way is also possible with Init() but below example is for postProcess

```
public function postProcess() 
{ 
    parent::postProcess(); 
    $id = (int)Tools::getValue('id_blahblah'); 
    $file = Tools::fileAttachment('img_any'); 
    if (!empty($file['name'])  && $id > 0) 
    { 
        if (ImageManager::validateUpload($file, Tools::convertBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize')))) 
            die('Image size exceeds limit in your PrestaShop settings'); 
        if (!is_dir(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'blah')) 
            @mkdir(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'blah', 0777, true); 
        if (!is_dir(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'blah/'.$id)) 
            @mkdir(_PS_IMG_DIR_.'blah/'.$id, 0777, true); 

        $path = _PS_IMG_DIR_.'blah/'.$id.'/'; 
        $absolute_path = $path.$file['name']; 
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $absolute_path); 
        $imgPath = 'blah/'.$id.'/'.$file['name']; 

        //Save in DB if needed
        Db::getInstance()->execute('UPDATE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'blah` 
        SET `img` = "'.pSQL($imgPath).'" 
        WHERE `id` = '.(int)$id); 
    } 
}
```